# Azure AD B2C - Angularjs sample (Web and Mobile) app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

How to use Azure AD B2C in angularJs based mobile and web apps?

Azure AD B2C is a cloud identity management solution for your web and mobile applications. It is a highly available global service that scales to hundreds of millions of identities

What are all the ways to use Azure AD B2C in apps?

Answer (score 0):

This sample demonstrates the use of AD B2C for securing an AngularJS based web and mobile app.

Refer https://github.com/NewtonJoshua/Azure-ADB2C-Angularjs-sample

#### Azure AD B2C

Azure AD B2C is a cloud identity management solution for your web and mobile applications. It is a highly available global service that scales to hundreds of millions of identities.

#### Web app - Hello.js

Web app implementation uses Hello.js that performs identity management with Azure AD B2C . Hello.js is a client-side JavaScript SDK for authenticating with OAuth2 web services and querying REST APIs.

#### Mobile app - ADAL plugin

Mobile app implementation uses ADAL Cordova Plugin Patch For B2C. This is a chopped version of Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) plugin for Apache Cordova apps, cordova-plugin-ms-adal that works with Azure AD B2C. The original cordova-plugin-ms-adal plugin provides easy to use authentication functionality for your Apache Cordova apps by taking advantage of Active Directory.

#### Decode JWT

jwtHelper of angular-jwt will take care of helping you decode the token (JWT) and check its expiration date. JSON Web Tokens are an open, industry standard RFC 7519 method for representing claims securely between two parties.

### 1. Project set up:

2. Clone or download this repository

   `git clone https://github.com/NewtonJoshua/Azure-ADB2C-Angularjs-sample.git`
3. Install dependencies

   `npm install`

   `bower install`

### 2. AD set up:

ADAL-B2C configuration

2. Create an Azure AD B2C Directory

   Note the ***Domain name***, it'll be used as the *tenantName*.
3. Register your application
   Follow the instructions to create an application and enable both Web App and Native client. Refer Register a web application and Register a mobile/native application

   Enter the *Reply URL* as http://localhost:8100 or any port from wher you'll be serving your app.

   In *Application Claims*, select Email Addresses too.

   Note the ***Application ID*** . It'll be used as the *clientId*.
4. Create a sign-up or sign-in policy

   Note the name of the policy. It'll be used as *policy*.
5. Create a password reset policy

   Note the name of the policy. It'll be used as the *password-reset-policy*

### 3. AD settings:

In settings.value.js, enter the following values

- tenantName: Domain name from step 2.1
- clientId: Application ID from step 2.2
- policy: policy name from step 2.3

### 4. Run this sample:

#### Web App:

From your shell or command line run

`ionic serve`

#### Mobile App:

2. Add platforms

`cordova platform add android`

`cordova platform add ios`

2. Generate icon and splash screen resources

`ionic cordova resources`

2. Build the App

`cordova build`

For more details on building the apps refer the Cordova documentions, Android Platform Guide and iOS Platform Guide

### 5. Customize the Azure AD B2C user interface

The Azure AD B2C login screen can be customized to suit our branding. Refer Customizing the UI

In this sample we have two customized UI screens,

- AD B2C Sign in ansd Sign up page: adCustomPages/unified.html
- AD B2C Password reset page: adCustomPages/resetpassword.html

In adCustomPages/unified.html, at line 442 and 445, enter your tenantName, password-reset-policy and clientId

The pages should be uploaded in a blob and their url should be referred in the Azure AD B2C policies.

- *Create a storage account* as mentioned in Upload the sample content to Azure Blob Storage
- Upload the sample AD Pages in the container and note down their url.
- For the created Blob service Storage account create a CORS rule with '*' as ALLOWED ORIGINS. Select all in ALLOWED METHODS. Enter * for ALLOWED HEADERS and EXPOSED HEADERS as well.
- Customize your policy

Now in your application you can see the customized UI.

### Implementation:

If you have to build an application based on this sample remember to install the required dependencies.

#### Web App

Dependencies:

`bower install ng-hello --save`

`bower install angular-jwt --save`

refer hello.service.js

#### Mobile App

Dependencies:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/jospete/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova --save`

`bower install angular-jwt --save`

refer adal.service.js

### Related documents:

2. Overview:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview
3. Azure AD - Help secure AngularJS single-page apps by using Azure AD
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular
4. Azure AD B2C: Single-page app sign-in by using OAuth 2.0 implicit flow
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-spa

Note:  [it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)